# Implement default value in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, default-value

I have a class containing a set of attributes, which I want to be able to have default values get from another instance (named parent).

If the instance does not have a parent, then it is assigned default values.
But if the instance have a parent, then I would like it to default its attributes to the parent's ones, *with the restriction* that if the parent attributes are modified then the object attributes can also get the new value.
Given this restriction, I can't simply copy the values from the parent.

Thus I think I have two methods:

- Use pointers: if the pointer is nullptr then use the parent value.
- Use a bool field for each attribute, indicating the status.

Both methods should work, but they also have incovenient:

- The first will need manual instantiation even if it can be simplified with shared_ptr or unique_ptr. But this will lead to additional instructions, thus slower code
- The second will lead to additional memory consumption : each instance will take at least one more byte (most of time 2, 4 or even 8 bytes) per attribute.

**My question is:** Is there any other way to implement such behavior? Or what is the best solution?

Comment: Your verbal description sounds a bit messy. Can you post some code how you would like to use this and how you would like it to behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The second will lead to additional memory consumption : each instance
>   will take at least one more byte (most of time 2, 4 or even 8 bytes)
>   per attribute.

Then use a bitfield or bit mask to use one single bit for each attribute. Nothing more efficient than that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following basic building block can be used: A defaultable reference:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct RefWithDefault
{
    /* external reference version */
    RefWithDefault(T & x) : r(x) { }

    /* default-initialize version */
    RefWithDefault() : p(new T), r(*p) { }

    /* value/direct-initialize version */
    template <typename ...Args> 
    RefWithDefault(Args &&... args) : p(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)), r(*p) { }

    T & operator() { return r; }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> p;
    T & r;
};
```

Now you can initialize such an object either with an existing reference, or leave it blank and it'll construct a new object to which you have a reference.

Comment: I will need both the additional field for each attribute and the manual allocation overhead no?